# Variadic Template And Ellipses

Tags: variadic-templates, ellipse

I have two function defined as follows

```
void Function( ... );

template < typename ... ARGS >
void Function1( ARGS ... args )
{
    // I have to call Function here
}
```

How can i pass variadic template arguments "args" to Function.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just call `Function(args...)`.

The `...` operator in C++11 expands template parameter packs which is exactly what you want here. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) for more details.